# Read a file which is present on logged in shell into string and do a loop using expect script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, tcl, expect

I have a expect shell script which is used to automate shell login using ssh and after login in I created a file on the logged in shell and I want to read and display the content of the file present on the logged in server.

My expect scrip looks like this what is does is
1. login to the shell using ssh
2. create a file there 
3. read content of the file created and display it.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn telnet 10.10.10.10
expect "login:*"
send "XXXXXX\r"
expect "Password*"
send "XXXXX\r"
expect "#"
send "ls -lrt > temp\r"
expect "#"
set f [open ./temp]
set entry [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
expect "#"
foreach line $entry {
    puts "$line\n"
}
exit
```

it says no temp file is present because it assume that file is present at the location from where the expect scrip is executed. But I want to read the file that I have created on the logged in shell. I am using Mac for scripting purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file is being created on the remote host yet you're trying to read it locally. If you've not got a shared filesystem between the two (very much not the default; you wouldn't be asking this question if you did!) that won't work.

Instead, you want to get the information written out remotely *in a format that is easy to digest* and then you parse it locally. The format part is something for you to think about going forward, but here's the rest of it:

```
spawn telnet 10.10.10.10
expect "login:*"
send "XXXXXX\r"
expect "Password*"
send "XXXXX\r"
expect "#"
send "ls -lrt\r"

# Create the accumulator so that won't be surprised if there's no remote output
set entry {}
# This is the multi-clause version of the expect command
expect {
    "#" {
        # Got a prompt; drop out of the expect
    }
    -re {^.*$} {
        # Got some other line; save and wait for the next one
        lappend entry $expect_out(0,string)
        exp_continue; # <<< MAGIC; asks expect to keep waiting
    }
}

foreach line $entry {
    puts "$line\n"
}
exit
```

Almost all questions about how to automate something slightly tricky with Expect seem to end up using the multi-clause version of `expect` with suitable `exp_continue` calls.

Answer (score 2):

You want to capture the output of the command, not create a temporary file:

```
set cmd "ls -lrt"
send "$cmd\r"
expect -re "$cmd\r\n(.*)\r\n#$"
set ls_output $expect_out(1,string)
puts $ls_output
```

We send the command, then expect to match a regular expression:

- the command we sent: `ls -lrt`
- a newline: expect always sends back `\r\n` for newlines.
- whatever the command outputs: `(.*)`
- a newline, your prompt character `#`, and the end of text

The text in the first set of capturing parentheses appears in the `expect_out` array with the array key `1,string`

If your prompt is not exactly a hash character with no leading or trailing characters, you'll need to adjust that regex accordingly.

A tip: while developing an expect script, enable debugging so you can see what does or doesn't match with your expect patterns: `expect -d script.exp`

Answer (score 1):

`ls -lrt > temp` runs on remote host (the telnet server) but `open ./temp` runs on the local host (the telnet client). You cannot directly open a file on remote server.